# wprintf: %p with NULL pointer

Tags: c, printf, glibc, widechar

As I was writing a unit test, I stumbled upon some odd behavior from `glibc`, regarding `"%p"` and the `NULL` pointer.

If I have a line such as `printf("NULL pointer is %p\n", NULL);`, then I see `NULL pointer is (nil)` printed to the screen, as I expected.

If I instead use the wide-character version: `wprintf(L"NULL pointer is %p\n", NULL);`, then it prints out `NULL pointer is (`, and stops at the opening parenthesis. If I print a non-`NULL` pointer, it prints that pointer, both normal and wide-character versions. Is this a known bug of `glibc`, or am I just missing something?

NB: I realize that the C standard says that pointers with `%p` are converted in an implementation-defined manner; it just seems unusual to just print `(` for a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: looks like a bug .....

Comment: The result strings do not match what one would expect from the format strings:  in the format strings, there are single quote marks (`'`) around the `%p`, but they do not appear in the result strings.  Is this a typo in the question?

Comment: Instead of `NULL`, have you tried `L'\0'`?

Comment: @FiddlingBits `%p` expects a pointer, whereas `L'\0'` is an integer constant. Regardless, it still gives the same result.

Comment: [This can't be right either](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ffa19139dad72878)...

Comment: @rubenvb that's because you can't mix `printf` and `wprintf` on the same stream - once a stream is oriented as either wide character or not, it can't be changed

Comment: @Drew First time I noticed this. Then again, I never mixed wide and non-wide output. [Nice answer on the matter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8682010/256138) (including comments).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is definitely a bug: https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/vfprintf.c;hb=c15cf13a8a672bd27bf3d94b995c52872eed537d#l932

```
 934             /* Write "(nil)" for a nil pointer.  */                           \
 935             string = (CHAR_T *) L_("(nil)");                                  \
 936             /* Make sure the full string "(nil)" is printed.  */              \
 937             if (prec < 5)                                                     \
 938               prec = 5;                                                       \
 939             is_long = 0;        /* This is no wide-char string.  */           \
 940             goto LABEL (print_string);                                        \
```

The `L_("(nil)")` expands to `L"(nil)"` for wprintf, but a couple of lines later `is_long` is set to `0` (i.e. false). As a result `string` is interpreted as a narrow-character string, so printing it will stop at its first zero byte i.e. after the `(`.

Reported bug link: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16890 - this is fixed in version 2.20 of glibc.

Interestingly, this bug appears to have existed for almost 15 years before it was found and fixed - within 2 days of its reporting!

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS; GNU C Library (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6).

It seems to be a [reported bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=729514) in at least Debian glibc; the bug [has been fixed](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;h=4fdfe821e20a70670b3d03deb2abed5d8c83e51b) on 1 May 2014, and should be available in Glibc 2.20. Just wait for upstream updates.