# c++: printf and wprintf don't work together (linux)

Tags: c++, printf, stdout, widechar

The code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    printf("printf\n");
    wprintf(L"wprintf\n");
}
```

https://onlinegdb.com/BkRqZttEE

http://cpp.sh/4ogx3

I read a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681623/printf-and-wprintf-in-single-c-code), but I didn’t know how to solve the problem of writing these commands in one code without hassle.

How to properly change orientation?

Comment: Why do you include `<iostream>`? You don't use anything from it. What you should include is `<stdio.h>` or `<cstdio>`.

Comment: @Deduplicator not cstdio unless they add namespace operators first.

Comment: @eerorika Yes, I thought I would leave that part as an exercise for the reader ;-)

Comment: @Andreyua But `::wprintf()` is not guaranteed part of it. I think it isn't even allowed to introduce it at all.

Comment: @Deduplicator it's allowed. But entirely unspecified whether it does.

Answer (score 1):

Once the orientation  is decided, there is no way back.

You could stop the process and start a new one to get a new stream.

Comment: @Andreyua clever. I hadn't thought of reopening `stdout`. Unfortunately the behaviour seems to be implementation defined at best however.