# How to coordinate printf and wprintf between executable and lazy-loaded shared-library?

Tags: c, printf, lazy-loading, wchar-t

My project consists of a main executable that runs a function from a lazy-loaded shared library:

```
// main.c
//
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  void* lhandle = dlopen("libfoo.so", RTLD_LAZY);

  // setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); // is here the right place for this?
  printf("hello\n");

  if (!lhandle) { return EXIT_FAILURE; }

  {
    void (*fptr)(void) = dlsym(lhandle, "run");

    if (fptr) { fptr(); }
  }

  dlclose(lhandle);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

```
// foo.c
//
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wchar.h>

void run() {
  wchar_t c = L'\x00f7'; // division sign

  // setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); // is here the right place for this?
  wprintf(L"%lc\n", c);
}
```

```
# CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

project(foo)

add_library(foo SHARED foo.c)

add_executable(main main.c)
target_link_libraries(main dl)
target_link_directories(main PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

In `main.c`, I have no need to print special characters, so I default to `printf` (for no reason other than out of habit).
But some of the shared libraries will need to print wide characters, they will need to `wprintf` instead of `printf`.
I'm not very experienced here, so my shallow understanding is that each `FILE` stream can have only one "width" so you can't mix `wprintf` and `printf` ([printf and wprintf in single C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681623/printf-and-wprintf-in-single-c-code)) -- and I imagine the `FILE` stream of relevance here is `stdout`.

**My question is about best practice in this/similar situations, where a "parent" program and "child" shared libraries have different print-width needs.**

Is best practice that the main program and shared libraries share a gentleman's agreement on the print-width?

Or should the "parent" program" and "child" shared library each change the print-width as needed? (would that be implemented as all printers calling `setlocale()` before calling `printf()` or `wprintf()`?).

Comment: Gut feel — if they share a file stream, they have to agree on the width.  I suspect best practice is to use separate streams.  Switching width is fairly expensive IIRC.

Comment: Open a separate stream to the output device and use that in your code, with `fprintf` instead of `printf`.

Comment: You can't change between narrow and wide after the orientation of the stream has been decided by `fwide()` or an I/o function.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - can you elaborate on what you said: "open a separate stream to the output device"? I don't think I'm familiar with that concept, or what its implementation would be.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - can you elaborate on what you said? I think my understanding of the term "stream" is a little fuzzy. Do you mean one should use `stdout` and the other `stderr`?

Comment: @StoneThrow: Call `fopen("/dev/stdout", "a")`, test the result, and use the new stream it provides. `"/dev/stdout"` is of course OS-specific, not strictly conforming C.

Comment: @Shawn Does that mean that whoever goes first (`wprintf` or `printf`) "wins" setting the stream's orientation? Is it literally set once and never again for the rest of this process?

Comment: From C spec, may be useful "Once a wide character input/output function has been applied to a stream without orientation, the stream becomes a wide-oriented stream. Similarly, once a byte input/output function has been applied to a stream without orientation, the stream becomes a byte-oriented stream. Only a call to the `freopen` function or the `fwide` function can otherwise alter the orientation of a stream. (A successful call to freopen removes any orientation.)"

Comment: @Shawn Concerning [... can't change between narrow and wide ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73172223/how-to-coordinate-printf-and-wprintf-between-executable-and-lazy-loaded-shared-l#comment129230436_73172223), a call to freopen removes any orientation.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Closing the old stream and opening a new one in its place doesn't count.

Comment: @StoneThrow Basically yes.

Comment: Wouldn't be possible to use UTF8 in every case?

Comment: @Shawn - your comment led me to a solution that works cleanly for my project: the "child" lazy-loaded library opens its own stream to `/dev/stdout`, leaving the "parent" and "child" free to `fprintf` or `fwprintf` at each's own discretion. From the comment discussion, I get the impression that there is no specific best practice or prevailing convention for this situation(?)

Comment: Note that C11 says that [§7.29.3.5 The `fwide` function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.29.3.5) can interrogate the byte/wide orientation of a stream.  It can set the byte/wide orientation if has not already been established.  It cannot change the byte/wide orientation once it has been set (_342) If the orientation of the stream has already been determined, `fwide` does not change it._).  So only a call to `freopen()` allows you to change the orientation.  Using `fclose()` and `fopen()` doesn't really count, though it does do the job; it isn't the same stream after the close/open.